# Assigning options from Listbox using VBA in Access 2013

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I am struggling with something on my project and I wondered if anybody would be able to point me in the right direction.

An image should be able to explain the functionality easier than I can describe it:

[image]

Quite simply, I want users to be able to click on 'Add' and then double click on one of the specialities to assign it to that DJ.

When the user clicks on the save button, a new row to a table called 'tblDJSpecialitiy' for each speciality they have chosen needs to be created. Each row needs to contain the 'Dj_No' and the primary key of what ever the speciality is.

First of all I need to work on getting specialities list on the Edit DJ form to update to reflect the specialities that the user click on from the list of all specialities.

Here is the code I currently have for the specialities list on the Edit DJ form:

```
Public Sub displaySpecialities()
'for the selected member display current loans (including overdue loans)
'and loans which have been returned but for which fines are still outstanding
Dim RstSpecialities As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSQL, strSpecialityInformation As String
Dim strDJNo As String
Dim intNumberOfSpecialities, intIndex As Integer
strDJNo = txt_dj_no.Value
'call the function to clear the list
Call clearLst_Specialities
'create an sql query to find the specialities
strSQL = strSQL & "SELECT tblSpeciality.SpecialityName FROM tblSpeciality INNER JOIN tblDJSpeciality ON tblDJSpeciality.[FKSpecialityNo] = tblSpeciality.[SpecialityNo] WHERE tblDJSpeciality.FKDjNo = '" & strDJNo & "';"
'store the results of the query in the recordset
Set RstSpecialities = dbase.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)
'calculate the number of specialities
If Not RstSpecialities.EOF Then
    RstSpecialities.MoveLast
    intNumberOfSpecialities = RstSpecialities.RecordCount
    RstSpecialities.MoveFirst
End If
'add the details of each speciality to the list box
For intIndex = 0 To intNumberOfSpecialities - 1
    strSpecialityInformation = RstSpecialities("SpecialityName")
    lst_specialities.AddItem (strSpecialityInformation)
    RstSpecialities.MoveNext
Next
'close the recordet
RstSpecialities.Close
End Sub
```

And here is the code which I currently have to populate the list of all specialities on the add form:

```
Public Sub displaySpecialities()
    'list all specialities in the system
    Dim RstSpecialities As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strSQL, strSpecialityInformation As String
    Dim intNumberOfSpecialities, intIndex As Integer
    'call the function to clear the list
    Call clearLst_Specialities
    'create an sql query to find the specialities
    strSQL = strSQL & "SELECT tblSpeciality.SpecialityName FROM tblSpeciality  ORDER BY SpecialityName ;"
    'store the results of the query in the recordset
    Set RstSpecialities = dbase.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)
    'calculate the number of specialities
    If Not RstSpecialities.EOF Then
        RstSpecialities.MoveLast
        intNumberOfSpecialities = RstSpecialities.RecordCount
        RstSpecialities.MoveFirst
    End If
    'add the details of each speciality to the list box
    For intIndex = 0 To intNumberOfSpecialities - 1
        strSpecialityInformation = RstSpecialities("SpecialityName")
        lst_speciality_add.AddItem (strSpecialityInformation)
        RstSpecialities.MoveNext
    Next
    'close the recordet
    RstSpecialities.Close
End Sub
```

I have been googling for a good while trying to work it - but without much luck. Thanks to anyone who replies.

EDIT:

[image]

This comes up twice - if I put in  '11' (the DJ number) both times then I get a list up - but it shows like this:

[image]

this seems to be all of the records in my tblDJSpecialty

Comment: I would simplify this by not having the 'Add' form, but instead having the listbox to  the right of your current specialties control. You can use the standard conventions of ">" "<" etc to add/delete. If you want to keep the popup form, you can omit the populate code by just having a query populate your listbox. When you click the Save button, that is where you need help with the code to Add / Delete specialties. Do you already have any code to try this?

Comment: Yes - I would definitely be willing to put both of the listboxes side-by-side if that would simplify things a little. Do you have any ideas how I could achieve this? - Also, no I do not have the code to actually add / delete the specialities when the DJ details get saved - I have not gotten that far yet! Many thanks for responding

Comment: Save a copy of your existing database to fall back to if needed. Then on the edit form, get rid of the Add & Delete buttons; shrink the width of the 'preference' listbox; add a new listbox control to the right; You can either insert two command buttons between the two lists, one with ">" one with "<" and add code to maintain the correct preferences, or you could have 'Double-Click' code so that it would add or delete a row on the form. I will throw together some code for how to maintain the database table and post it in a few minutes.

Comment: Thank you - I have just redesigned my form and am now starting work on writing the code to move items between the two lists.

Comment: Are you going to use the command buttons with > and < or use Double-Click to add/delete? I created your form and tables, but in doing so, there is an easier way to handle the listbox for Preferences. I just created a query based on joining tblPreferences and tblDJInfo(?) with the criteria being your DJ_No control. Then in the Form_Current event, I just requery the Preference listbox. My thinking is rather than have the 'Add' button maintain the DB list, have the < > code maintain the table, then just requery. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, I like the < > method better - and have put those buttons in, I was just trying to work out how to get those < > buttons to move the items over

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is some code that will add/delete specialties between the two list boxes. But first, a few explanations:

- The listbox on the left (lst_specialities)is for the individual DJ specialties
- The listbox on the right (lst_specialities_All) contains ALL specialties to choose from
- tblSpeciality has two columns: (1) SpecialityNo, AutoNumber, PK; (2) SpecialityName Text
- Table tblDJSpecialityID has 3 columns: (1) DJSpecialityID AutoNumber, PK; (2) DJ_FKDjNo LongInt (DJ's PK); (3) FKSpecialityNo, LongInt (PK of Speciality)
- Change the names used to match your names.
- The following is the rowsource SQL of the Preferences listbox 'lst_specialities'

  ```
  SELECT tblDJSpecialitiy.DJSpecialityID, tblDJSpecialitiy.DJ_FKDjNo, tblDJSpecialitiy.FKSpecialityNo, tblSpeciality.SpecialityName FROM tblDJSpecialitiy 
  INNER JOIN tblSpeciality ON tblDJSpecialitiy.FKSpecialityNo = tblSpeciality.SpecialityNo 
  WHERE (((tblDJSpecialitiy.DJ_FKDjNo)=[Forms]![dj_edit]![txt_dj_no]));
  ```
- The following is the rowsource of the listbox 'lst_specialities_All':

  ```
  SELECT tblSpeciality.SpecialityNo, tblSpeciality.SpecialityName 
  FROM tblSpeciality ORDER BY tblSpeciality.SpecialityName;
  ```

The following is the code for adding / deleting. I named the command buttons cmdPlus and cmdMinus:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Current()
    Me.lst_specialities.Requery
End Sub

Private Sub cmdMinus_Click()
Dim strSQL  As String
Dim i       As Integer

    If Me.lst_specialities.ItemsSelected.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "You must select a specialty to remove from this DJ.", vbOKOnly, "No Specialty Selected"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For i = 0 To 3
        Debug.Print i & vbTab & Me.lst_specialities.Column(i)
    Next i
    strSQL = "DELETE tblDJSpecialitiy.DJSpecialityID, tblDJSpecialitiy.FKSpecialityNo " & _
                "FROM tblDJSpecialitiy " & _
                "WHERE (((tblDJSpecialitiy.DJSpecialityID)=" & Me.lst_specialities.Column(0) & "));"
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True

    UnSelect_All
    UnSelect_DJ
    Me.lst_specialities.Requery
End Sub

Private Sub cmdPlus_Click()
Dim strSQL  As String
Dim i       As Integer


    If Me.lst_specialities_All.ItemsSelected.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "You must select a specialty to add to this DJ.", vbOKOnly, "No Specialty Selected"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For i = 0 To 3
        Debug.Print i & vbTab & Me.lst_specialities_All.Column(i)
    Next i
    strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblDJSpecialitiy ( DJ_FKDjNo, FKSpecialityNo ) " & _
            "SELECT " & Me.txt_dj_no & " AS Expr1, " & Me.lst_specialities_All.Column(0) & " AS Expr2;"
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True

    UnSelect_All
    UnSelect_DJ

    Me.lst_specialities.Requery
End Sub

Function UnSelect_All()
Dim i  As Integer
    For i = 0 To Me.lst_specialities_All.ListCount             'Deselect ALL rows in Listbox
        lst_specialities_All.Selected(i) = False
    Next i

End Function
Function UnSelect_DJ()
Dim i  As Integer
    For i = 0 To Me.lst_specialities.ListCount             'Deselect ALL rows in Listbox
        lst_specialities.Selected(i) = False
    Next i

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks so much for going to so much trouble to help! It's late where I am and I have to sleep, but I will be using this tomorrow. Thanks again!

Comment: Forgot to mention that you will need to make sure of how many columns in the listbox and the order of values. Where I have used 'Me.lst_specialities.Column(0)' that is for the primary key of the record.

Comment: Hi - do you have any idea why the rowsource SQL for the left hand DJ specialities listbox is not loading anything? I have adapted your query with my own table names etc, as follows: `SELECT tblDJSpecialitiy.DJSpecialityID, tblDJSpecialitiy.DJ_FKDjNo, tblDJSpecialitiy.FKSpecialityNo, tblSpeciality.SpecialityName FROM tblDJSpecialitiy 
INNER JOIN tblSpeciality ON tblDJSpecialitiy.FKSpecialityNo = tblSpeciality.SpecialityNo
WHERE (((tblDJSpecialitiy.FKDjNo)=[Forms]![dj_edit]![txt_dj_no]));` It is just giving me a blank listbox

Comment: Are you sure you have records in your table? And that the keys map correctly between the two tables and the listbox columns? I changed all my names to match your and will update the Answer with the latest and an explanation of the table formats. I need to leave here in about 25 minutes...

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. Sorry I missed you - I was getting myself mixed up with the US/UK spelling of specialty / speciality! (oops) Now for some reason I am getting a new popup when I click on edit (I have attached image to the main question above - if you wouldn't mind having a look) - I've checked and my form is definitely called 'dj_edit' and my text box is definitely called 'txt_dj_no'

Comment: (1) I just wrote a lengthy suggestion, but now noticed your table name is 'TDL...' and not 'TBL...'; (2) I would swap the two listboxes (left and right) to make the flow look better by keeping the DJ info on the left; (3) I would change the button labels from 'cmdPlus' & minus to something like just "<" and ">" or "< Add" and "> Remove".; (4) Set the column widths for the listboxes to "0" to hide all but the 'Name" column. Let me know how it goes...

Comment: sorry - I am unsure what you mean when you say my table name is TDL and not TBL? where is this? I'll be tidying up the form and renaming the buttons once I get this thing working - but at the moment it persists with the 'Enter Parameter Value' popup - which I do not understand?

Comment: The image you inserted above - is asking for a parameter from "tdlDJSpecialitiy.DJ_FKDjNo' and it should be 'tblDJSpecialitiy.DJ_FKDjNo'  that means you have a problem in a query

Comment: Ah-HA! It is working! Thank you for all your trouble. I think it definitely says 'tbl' in the image I inserted. The problem was that it was looking for 'DJ_FKDjNo' ... the column is actually 'FKDjNo'. I cannot believe I didn't spot that. Now what I would quite like is to set it so that the same speciality cannot be assigned multiple times / duplicated. I will have a go at looking into that tomorrow as it is nearly 4am here. Thanks so much

Comment: That's a simple solution. Add a Unique key to the table that is made up of DJ_FKDjNo and FKSpecialityNo. I had already used code to turn warnings off, then on, when running the SQL to add a specialty.